# Jittery Animation Issue on Safari iOS: Possible Causes and Video Demo

Tags: css, ios, css-animations, parallax, gsap

An animation of image movement based on vertical scroll has been implemented. However, the animation of the image movement is jittery on Safari iOS (see the video below). The image movement is animated using the CSS property transform: translate3d. What could be the possible reasons for this issue?

GSAP's ScrollTrigger is used. will-change doesn't give impact.
On desktop Chrome, the animation doesn't jitter. If smooth scrolling is used, it fixes the issue. However, it is necessary to have native scroll on iOS as it performs better, but the animation still jitters. We tested it on different versions of Safari iOS, and the jittering issue persists.

If the scroll is not released, the animation stops jittering. However, when performing swipes, the animation starts to jitter. I have attached a video showcasing the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KSfNerxhE5jvRAp0SiK1z4VX0PHPAioB/view?usp=sharing